# How to tie login credentials to Touch ID

Tags: swift2, touch-id

I understand how to set up Touch ID using the LocalAuthenticationFramework but I'm very confused on how to tie someone's Touch ID to their login credentials in my app. Ultimately what I'd like to do is offer Touch ID option to login to my app with an option that they can enter username and password manually. I just cant find anywhere how to know when that person logs in with their Touch ID that it is a certain user. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot find that information. All you know is that the Touch ID succeeded or not.

So the first time you ask for the user's fingerprint you must save the login credentials (or some other secure token) in the keychain. And the second time, after they authenticate with the finger, you then retrieve those credentials from the keychain and login with them.

Comment: Thank you Paul, I was wondering in my head if I needed to use the keychain because that was all that made sense to me but now you have confirmed it.